# Set-theoretic difficulties concerning normality

Tags: general-topology, logic

In her "Lectures on Set Theoretic Topology" Mary Ellen Rudin states at the end of page 5 that "In the case on nomality this is made doubly difficult by the fact that normality is such a second order property that it can often not be decided whether a given topological space is normal or not within the usual axioms for set theory."

What does it means "nomality is such a second order property"? And why this is a particularity of normality? The regularity isn't a second order property?

Is it possible to define a topological space in ZFC such that it is undecidable wheter this space is normal or not?

Comment: maybe what she means is that it universally quantifies twice over the set of all closed subsets (for all closed C, for all closed D, there exist disjoint open sets etc). regular just quantifies over all closed subsets and all points. but i don't really know.

Comment: Normality is a property about sets. Consider $\forall x\forall y P(x,y)$. In first order logic, the variables range over the elements of some set. In second order logic, the variables can range over sets. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it means "normality is such a second order property"?

It means that the statement "$X$ is a normal space" requires non-trivial quantification over the subsets of some set. In particular, for a topological space $(X,\tau)$ with base $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau$, the assertion that  $X$ is normal, is equivalent to the following, second-order, statement,

$$\forall A,B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{B})\, \exists U, V \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{B}): \text{ either } (\cup A) \cup (\cup B) \neq X, \text{ or } \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (X\backslash \cup A) \backslash \cup U= \emptyset,\,\,  (X\backslash \cup B)\backslash \cup V = \emptyset, \text{ and } (\cup U) \cap (\cup V) = \emptyset.$$

> Is it possible to define a topological space in ZFC such that it is undecidable whether this space is normal or not?

*Yes.*

A nice way to do this is to consider the spaces associated with ladder systems on $\omega_1$.

**Definition**:

1. A Ladder System on a stationary set $S \subset \lim(\omega_1)$ is an $S$-indexed sequence $M=\langle M_\gamma: \gamma \in S\rangle$ of countable subsets of $\omega_1$, such that, $\operatorname{ot}(M_\gamma) = \omega\,$  and $\,\sup (M_\gamma) = \gamma $.
2. For each ladder system $M=\langle M_\gamma: \gamma \in S\rangle$, we let $X_M$ denote the topological space defined on the set $A=\omega_1 \times \{0\} \cup S \times \{1\}$, by letting each $(\gamma, 0) \in A$ be isolated and taking as basic open neighborhoods of each $(\gamma,1) \in A$, sets of the form $\{ (\gamma,1) \} \cup B$ where $B \subset M_\gamma \times \{0\}$ co-finite.

As it turns out, whether *any* of the spaces $X_M$ are normal, is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$; for a nice discussion of this result, see the paper,

> *Balogh, Zoltán; Eisworth, Todd; Gruenhage, Gary; Pavlov, Oleg; Szeptycki, Paul*, [**Uniformization and anti-uniformization properties of ladder systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm181-3-1), Fundam. Math. 181, No. 3, 189-213 (2004). [ZBL1051.03034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1051.03034).,

Comment: But isn't also the regularity a second order property?

Comment: @Ottaviano It turns out that regularity is equivalent to a much simpler statement of the form "there is some base with a certain first-order property" which means the property behaves much nicer.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear